# access node data and fill accordingly on observablehq forcegraph

Tags: javascript, observablehq

I am accessing the following sample page on observablehq.
[Force directed graph](https://observablehq.com/@d3/disjoint-force-directed-graph)

At the moment the page colors node based on group.

I am struggling to do the following:

- colorfill (with a specific colour) a node (or all nodes) based on a value of the node

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group accessor allows you to access each node, in the example it is accessing the `group` property of the node: `nodeGroup: d => d.group`.

The example also uses a ordinal scale, if you want to use continuous values from your nodes you could fork the example (or copy the whole function) and change the d3.scaleOrdinal to something like d3.scaleLinear